# External Sort between two files

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, external-sorting

I'm trying to get my head around an external sort for a requirement I have - and I can't.

The requirement is to externally sort a file of an arbitrary size but using just the original file and one other (call them `fileA` and `fileB`) - two files including the original. I can read/write to either of these - so can swap between the two...

I cannot figure out how to implement this - as most sorting algorithms require you to be able to have an overview of the entire array in memory to sort it, surely?

Say I have a random integer array:

```
[1, 5, 8, 7, 3, 4, 1, 9, 0, 1, 8, 7, 7, 3, 2, 9, 1, 2];
```

And at any given time, I can only read four pages (e.g. four integers) into memory.

On each pass, this gives me five separate arrays to sort:

```
[1, 5, 8, 7]
[3, 4, 1, 9] 
[0, 1, 8, 7] 
[7, 3, 2, 9]
[1, 2]
```

If I apply an in-memory sort on these, I then get:

```
[1, 5, 7, 8]
[1, 3, 4, 9] 
[0, 1, 7, 8] 
[2, 3, 7, 9]
[1, 2]
```

But if I can only fit four pages into memory at any one time, I don't see how I can further sort these without some horrible complex algorithm which loops over the entire array again and again to ensure its all sorted.

I'm thoroughly confused - because without reading the entire array into memory, we have no idea what elements are before the four pages, or after - so we cannot truly sort them?

Can somebody help me please and explain the crucial step in solving this?

Comment: did you read the [wikpedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)?

Comment: Yeah - it seemed to imply an arbitrary number of files to write to which I don't have the luxury of.

Comment: The algorithm isn't quick or simple.  You start by comparing page 1 with page two moving the smallest number to page 1.  Then store page two into  2nd file.  The compare page 1 with page 3 again moving all smallest numbers to page one.  Continue until all pages are read from first into 2nd file.  Then save first page back into empty first file.  Now read new first page from 2nd file and compare with all other pages.  Now read 1st page from first file and save into 2nd file.  Then save 2nd sorted page in 2nd file.  Continue until all pages sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, the basic idea of External Sort is to merge the lists that are bigger than the available memory, therefore you control the lists (which may be actually implemented as arrays or linked lists or anything else) by means of a *handle* over them. In order to read an element from a list, you will use some method like `listHandle.getNextElement()`. To write to disk in the list, use `mergedDoubleSizedList.writeNextElement()`.

After you have:

```
[1, 5, 7, 8] // controlled using handle1
[1, 3, 4, 9] // controlled using handle2
[0, 1, 7, 8] // controlled using handle3
[2, 3, 7, 9] // controlled using handle4
[1, 2] // controlled using handle5
```

and that you read only 4 ints, you get the handle over the first two arrays (*handle1* and *handle2*), read them element by element simultaneously, and write them back as one consolidated array which is sorted (*mergedListHandle1*). Like this:

```
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9] // written by creating new handle - mergedListHandle1
[0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 8, 9] // written by creating - mergedListHandle2
[1, 2] // written back by creating mergedListHandle3
```

Now again you get the handle over two of the arrays (*mergedListHandle1* and *mergedListHandle2*) resulting from the previous step and keep merging them on and on until you are left with only two handles, resulting in one final sorted array. Please provide your code if you want the code based solution for the same.

At a time, you will have only 4 elements in the memory if that's what your memory allows. So, to merge the lists represented by *handle1* and *handle2*, you will do the following:

1. Read first element from handle1 and handle2 (`1` and `1`)
2. Write the smaller of these two to mergedListHandle1 (i.e. write `1` of handle1)

   1. You may not flush the numbers in mergedListHandle1 at the moment.
3. Read next element from handle1 (`5`)
4. Write the smaller of the current numbers from handle1 and handle2 to mergedListHandle1
5. Flush the contents of mergedListHandle1 when it is full
6. Fetch next smaller handles from disks (handle3 and handle4) and repeat the same cycle with them while you write to the new bigger list handle called mergedListHandle2.

Comment: @displayName - Random access overhead on a hard drive is an issue. The time it takes to do a random access and read 16 elements with a single I/O isn't much different than the time do a random access and read one element at a time. Unless using a SSD instead of a hard drive or if not using large I/O (like 10+MB per I/O), then a 4 way merge could end up slower than a 2 way merge due to random access overhead.

Comment: @rcgldr: Yes it is likely that a 4-way merge could be slower in general. But if instead of just having enough memory for 4 elements, you had 1GB memory to sort 1TB elements, m-way merge works better.

Comment: @displayName - I agree, as suggested in the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) with I/O at 10MB or more, a 9 way merge sort would make sense. With 1GB of memory, a 16 way merge sort would make sense. The code for a k-way merge is a bit more complicated, since when the end of one of the runs is reached, it's a k-1 way merge, then a k-2 way merge, ... until it's out of all but one run which is just copied.

Comment: @so my main comments are that this would be a [bottom up merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation) and explaining that listHandle.getNextElement() uses a combination of a file pointer and an index to get next elements from sub-lists buffered in memory, and somehow indicates that the end of sub-list has been reached. On a side note, it might be easier to start off with a 2 way merge, before trying a 4 way merge.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation for a simple 2 way bottom up merge sort.
Consider the data as 18 runs of size 1. Since the size is 1, each run can be considered sorted.

```
[1] [5] [8] [7] [3] [4] [1] [9] [0] [1] [8] [7] [7] [3] [2] [9] [1] [2]
```

On each pass, even runs are merged with odd runs from left to right from a source array or file into a destination array or file. After each pass, the roles of source and destination are swapped.

First pass

```
[1 5] [7 8] [3 4] [1 9] [0 1] [7 8] [3 7] [2 9] [1 2]
```

Second pass

```
[1 5 7 8] [1 3 4 9] [0 1 7 8] [2 3 7 9] [1 2]
```

Third pass

```
[1 1 3 4 5 7 8 9] [0 1 2 3 7 7 8 9] [1 2]
```

Forth pass

```
[0 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 7 7 7 8 8 9 9] [1 2]
```

Fifth pass (done)

```
[0 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 7 7 7 8 8 9 9]
```

The main variables are run size, and 4 indices for the starts and ends of a pair of runs (even and odd). The last run ends at the end of data and could be an even or odd run. For an external sort, the indices become file pointers.

An external sort only needs 2 memory locations to hold data, one element from an even run, one element from an odd run. The two elements are compared, the lower or equal one written to the destination file, and the next element from that run is read. If the end of that run is reached, then the other element is written and the rest of the other run is copied to the destination file. The two file pointers are advanced to the start of the next pair of even and odd runs, and the merge is continued, until the end of data is reached, ending the merge pass. Run size is doubled, the roles of source and destination files are swapped, and the next merge pass is done, repeating until run size become >= number of elements.

Comment: This is awesome - and it makes sense now; thanks so much :)